# unable to load FDF's in firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-acrobat

If I go to Options -> Applications I see this:

[image]

When I then view a PDF with an FDF in Firefox I get a "This PDF document might not be displayed correctly" warning and none of the fields are populated.

Google searches suggest switching the PDF you're using to Adobe Acrobat. Except that, as per the above screenshot, I should already be using Adobe Acrobat.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to [Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-built-pdf-viewer-and-use-another-viewer), you need to set that "Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox)" setting for the "Content Type" of "Portable Document Format (PDF)".

Your screenshot is from Adobe Acrobat Forms Documents. You probably have "Portable Document Format (PDF)" set to "Preview in Firefox", which opens it in pdf.js instead of Acrobat. Switch it to Adobe and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by allquixotic:

It isn't necessary to disable firefox's built-in PDF previewer. When you download within the previewer (top-right icon with the downwards-facing arrow) you are given the option to either save, or open with your preferred external application.